# Is it possible to refactor a map inside of a map inside of a map

Tags: scala, future

My service layer is returning Futures.
I have this mess currently:

```
userService.getAll().map { users =>
  for(u <- users) {
    groupService.getByUserId(u.id).map {
       blockingService.call(u)
       otherService.bar(u.id).map {
         lastService.foo(u.id)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can I clean this up somehow?  It has too many embedded map calls.

I am also scared that if in the future I refactor my code such that blockingService.call becauses Future based, my code will have unexpected problems potentially, so better to treat it as a Future?

Answer (score 3):

Replace the nested `map`s with a for comprehension:

```
  def doSomethingWithUser(u: User) = {
    for {
      _ <- groupService.getByUserId(u.id)
      _ <- Future(blockingService.call(u)) // Notice Future.apply here.
      _ <- otherService.bar(u.id)
      result <- lastService.foo(u.id)
    } yield result
  }

  for {
    users <- userService.getAll()
    results <- Future.traverse(users)(doSomethingWithUser) // Notice Future.traverse here.
  } yield results
```

Comment: wow, thanks man.  I need to get a chicken to teach me this stuff :)

Comment: A chicken - so you can see what coding this way entrails?

Comment: That probably should have been `Future#apply` instead of `Future#successful`. Have updated answer.